# C# Adding TableAdapter Query @parameter as int and date?

Tags: c#, sql, tableadapter

I was creating a query for the Table Adapter that looked like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Trip WHERE ShipCode = @ShipCode 
                           AND Date < @TodayPlusWeek
```

The thing is this method will expect (string, string) as parameter where I need it to accept **int** for the (*ShipCode*) and **Date** for the (*Date*)

Any ideas how to do that?

Very much appreciated!

Comment: Please verify that the strings are within the method and that the Sql columns are as int & Datetime

Comment: the columns in the table are already int and date

Comment: `SqlParameter`  takes a type parameter. Just specify the right type.

Answer (score 0):

The first part will be to set up a pair of variables of the proper type to hold the correct values for the Sql Parameters:

```
int iShipCode;
DateTime dtTodayPlusWeek;
```

Once you have that, we are going to run a `TryParse` method on your current string variables to convert into our new variables. As I did not know the variable names within your method, I generic'd them to (strShipCode, strTodayPlusWeek). If the TryParse method fails, you can set up default values for the query; I used 0 and Today + 1 week.

```
if (!int.TryParse(strShipCode, out iShipCode)) {
    iShipCode = 0;
}
if (!DateTime.TryParse(strTodayPlusWeek, out dtTodayPlusWeek)) {
    dtTodayPlusWeek = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
}
```

Now that we have correct types for the data, we can add that to our existing query as parameters.

```
StringBuilder sbCmd = new StringBuilder();
  sbCmd.Append("SELECT COUNT(*) ");
  sbCmd.Append("FROM Trip ");
  sbCmd.Append("WHERE (ShipCode = @ShipCode) ");
  sbCmd.Append("AND Date < @TodayPlusWeek");

string txtCmd = sbCmd.ToString();

int iQryReturn;

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(txtCmd, conn)) {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType .Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShipCode", iShipCode;);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TodayPlusWeek", dtTodayPlusWeek);

    try {
        conn.Open();
        iQryReturn = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        iQryReturn = -1;
        // Your Exception handling here
    }
    finally {
        conn.Close();
        // Your cleanup code if any
    }
}
```

Not knowing what type of DB setup you have in use, I have written this in ADO for Sql Server. Ad there will only be value returned; the count(*), I have added an integer variable for a return. If there is an error, that value will be set to -1.

It is up to you on implementation and syntactical changes that may be needed for your particular application.